# TextView below NestedScrollView with height wrap_content not visible

Tags: android

Below is the layout file of the bottom sheet. I have a `TextView` below the nested scroll view. When the content is large, the `TextView` below the `NestedScrollView` is not visible. If content of NestedScrollView is small it is visible. I am not getting what's causing this.

Here is my layout file:

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/bottom_sheet_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
            app:title="My Title">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end"
                android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackgroundBorderless"
                android:onClick="@{() -> handler.hideBottomSheet()}"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp" />

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/selection_mode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                android:checkedButton="@+id/mode_1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/mode_1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/mode_1" />

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/mode_2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/mode_2" />

            </RadioGroup>

            <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/list_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" />

            </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/list_description"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="This text is not visible. I dunno why! :/" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

`list_container` LinerLayout is inflated on Runtime. There are some reasons I am not using `RecyclerView` or `ListView`. This is fairly small, Just a little scrolling sometime.

But the TextView `list_description` is not being displayed when `list_container` is large (needs scrolling).

I am not getting it what's going wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `android:layout_weight` on your `NestedScrollView`.

In your case, replace the header of your `NestedScrollView` with:

> ```
> <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
>                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
>                 android:layout_height="0dp"
>                 android:layout_weight="1"
> ```

Hope that helps =]