# Android NestedScrollView ViewPager wrap_content

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-nestedscrollview

I am using a nestedscrollview as I have recyclerview and other views in the same Activity. I even need to add a view pager in the same activity in between a list and a view. I see that view pager is not occupying any space if I put the height as wrap_content. It shows up if I hard code the height. I need the viewpager to be wrapped as the content in the pager may increase or decrease.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@color/white"
                app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
                tools:context="com.neighboure.customer.activity.ProductDetailActivity"
                tools:showIn="@layout/activity_product_detail">

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="@dimen/_10sdp">

                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                    android:id="@+id/productsimgrecycleview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="@dimen/_60sdp">

                </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

                  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/des_spec_container"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="180dp"
                    />


            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btncart"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@color/lightgrey"
                    android:text="@string/label_add_to_cart"
                    android:textColor="@color/black"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Please find the below screenshots for reference

[image]

As you can see in the above picture the content in viewpager is visile as I have hard coded the height of the view pager.

[image]

In the above picture, I have wrapped the viewpager and the content is not visible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Set height to _match_parent_ for _NestedScrollView_

Comment: and also android:fillViewport="true"

Comment: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/android-viewpager-nestedscrollview-bukhori-aqid

Comment: http://www.jianshu.com/p/28e4346a41cf

Comment: I apply android:fillViewport="true"  to the NestedScrollView and now its working.

Answer (score 2):

```
 NestedScrollView scrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById (R.id.nest_scrollview);
    scrollView.setFillViewport (true);
```

you can see [ViewPager in a NestedScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30580954/viewpager-in-a-nestedscrollview)

Answer (score 0):

Might consider replacing

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

with a combination of

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
android:layout_weight="1"
```

See [TextView below NestedScrollView with height wrap_content not visible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39515256/textview-below-nestedscrollview-with-height-wrap-content-not-visible/39515611#39515611).